# PDF of the linear combination of two order statistics

Tags: mathematical-statistics, density-function, independence, order-statistics

I have just started to learn order statistics so please feel free to correct my notation/terminology.

In my field is common to provide data as the median of some sample (for example several simulations of an experiment) and the uncertainties in therms of $16th$ and $84th$ percentiles. The problem that I am facing is that these percentiles are clearly asymmetric from the median, so the distribution seem to be strongly non gaussian.
I decided to model the data from the point of view of order statistics. After some tedious algebra I managed to get the joint pdf of there order statistics, but after that I realized that the percentiles do not need to match with any real number from the sample i.e. if I have $9$ data the $50th$ percentile will be the $5th$ point, but if I have $10$ data the $50th$ percentiles is usually the average between the $5$th and the $6$th data. In general any percentile will be the weighted mean of two consecutive data points.

For simplicity I want to start with obtaining the probability distribution of one of the percentiles (I will try to get the joint probability of three percentiles later).

The idea I have is start from the the joint distribution of two consequent data. Which can be written as:
$$f_{X_{i}, X_{i+1}}\left(x_i, x_{i+1}\right) = \frac{N!}{(i-1)!(N-i-1)!}F(x_i)^{i-1}[1-F(x_{i+1})]^{N-i-1}f(x_i)f(x_{i+1})$$

As commented before the percentile will (in general) be the weighted mean of those two variables. Explicitly:
$$X_{i+\alpha}=(1-\alpha)X_{i} + \alpha X_{i+1},\hspace{2em} \alpha\in[0,1].$$

Following [this post about the pdf of the sample median](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/512342/find-the-pdf-of-the-sample-median-m-when-n-is-even-order-statistics), I tried to make a change of variables to this new set:
$(U, X_{i+\alpha}) = \left(X_{i+1} , (1-\alpha)X_{i} + \alpha X_{i+1}\right)$, and integrate out the $U$.

Which lead to (I think):

$$f_{X_{i+\alpha}} = \frac{N!}{(i-1)!(N-i-1)!}\int_{X_{i+\alpha}}^{\infty} \frac{dU}{(1-\alpha)}F\left(\frac{X_{i+\alpha}-\alpha U}{1 -\alpha}\right)^{i-1}\left[1-F(U)\right]^{N-i-1}f\left(\frac{X_{i+\alpha}-\alpha U}{1 -\alpha}\right)f(U)$$

I am integrating from $X_{i}$ to $\infty$ as by definition $X_{i+1}>X_{i}$. Is this right or should I integrate from $-\infty$?

Can I continue simplifying the pdf? or do I need to asume a shape for $f$ and $F$?

## EDIT

---

I have tried to program it to check wether it works or not, and it seems a little bit biased and I am not sure why.

I have computed the 10th percentile of 128 samples from a uniform distribution 10K times. You can see it in the histogram of the figure.
In orange I also show the expected pdf from the equation derived before. For this particular dataset $\alpha=0.8$, $i=12$ and $N=128$.
You can clearly see how it deviates one from another.

I have also included some code to reproduce the plot.

[image: 10K random realizations of the 10th percentile from 128 samples from a uniform distribution between 0 an 1 (blue) and the expected PDF from equation in text]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def log_fac(x):
   """
   Auxiliar function to compute the logarithm of the factorial of x:
   """
   return np.sum(np.log(np.arange(1, x+1))) 

def percentile_statistic(xx, perc, N, FF, ff, ubound=np.inf):
   """
   Compute the provability of the <prec>-th percentile at <xx> given that we had <N> samples from the underlaying distribution described via the PDF (<ff>) and CDF (<FF>).
   params :
   --------
   xx   : array-like, at which points do we want the probability
   perc : float, which percentile we are interested in. Should be between [0, 100]
   N    : int, number of samples we got from the distribution
   FF   : callable, Objective CDF. FF(xx)
   ff   : callable, Objective PDF. ff(xx)
   ubound : float, user bound of the domine. Default np.inf. It will be pass to spicy.integrate.quad as the upper limit of the integral 
   """
   ii = int(np.floor(perc*N/100))

   assert ii > 0, "If ii==0 we should compute the PDF of the minima." # we end up having a 0^-1, as is implemented right now
   assert ii < N, "If ii==N we should compute the PDF of the maxima" # We end up having a 0^-0 as is implemented right now
   
   # how much is left to reach X_{i+alpha} form X_{i} 
   alpha = perc*N/100 - ii

   # Compute the normalization
   log_norm = log_fac(N) - log_fac(ii-1) - log_fac(N-ii-1)
   norm = np.exp(log_norm)

   # auxiliar functions with the integrand
   x_i = lambda U, x: (x-alpha*U)/(1-alpha)
   integrand = lambda U, x: FF(x_i(U, x))**(ii-1)*(1-FF(U))**(N-ii-1)*ff(x_i(U, x))*ff(U)*norm/(1-alpha)

   return np.array([quad(lambda U: integrand(U, x), x, ubound)[0] for x in xx ])
 

def empirical_percentile_statistics(perc, N, itt=10000):
    """
    This is only valid for a Uniform distribution. It gets <N> samples from a Uniform distribution and computes the <perc>-th percentile, <itt> times.
    params: 
    -------
    perc : float, the percentile we are interested in 
    N    : int, number of samples per realization
    itt  : int, number of realizations
    """
    rnd = np.zeros(itt)
    for ii in range(itt):   
       _rd = np.random.random(N)
       rnd[ii] = np.percentile(_rd, perc)

    return rnd 



def pdf_uniform(x, ulim=1, llim=0):
    """
    PDF of uniform distribution
    """
    if (x <= llim) or (x >= ulim): 
        return 0
    else:
        return 1/(ulim-llim)

def cdf_uniform(x, ulim=1, llim=0):
    """
    CXDF of uniform distribution
    """
    if x <= llim:
       return 0
    elif x >= ulim:
       return 1
    else:
       return (x-llim)/(ulim-llim)


## Lets start
N     = 128
perc  = 10
Nreal = 10000
FF    = cdf_uniform
ff    = pdf_uniform

xx = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)

analytical_pdf = percentile_statistic(xx, perc, N, FF, ff, ubound=1)
numerical_sampling = empirical_percentile_statistics(perc, N, itt=Nreal)

# start ploting
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(numerical_sampling, bins=100, range=(0, 1), density=True)
ax.plot(xx, analytical_pdf)


ax.set_xlabel(r"$x_{{{}th}}$".format(perc))
ax.set_ylabel(r"$f(x_{{{}th}}| N={})$".format(perc, N))

ax.set_xlims(0, .2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How does this help you give the 16th, 50th, and 84th percentiles?

Comment: This derivation is correct, but (a) you cannot integrate without using a specific form of the distribution ($f$ and $F$ need be set) and (b) this is only providing the distribution of the $\alpha$-th percentile. If you need the joint distribution of the $\alpha$-th and $\beta$-th percentiles, this will require a double integral.

Comment: Hi! And thanks for the welcome!  I will need to work a little bit to get the join pdf of the 3 percentiles, as for doing so I may need to get the joint PDF of 6 order statistics and repeat this process but in paris. I mainly wanted to know whether what I was doing was correct, prior going to the next step. And also if someone knew any "trick" to simplify the integral as I will have 3 at the end!.

Comment: Hi @Dave ! (sorry for not metioning you before) I do not want to provide the percentiles (I already have them) but to model the provability distribution of my data with them to latter make a fit. For example, imagine that I want to fit the orbital periods ($T$) of plates vs the distance to the sun ($r$) (i.e. Keppler third law). That has the from $T = cr^{3/2}$, imagine that someone has measured the distances and periods but due to noise (no necessarily gaussian)  they have a distribution of measurements, but instead of providing all the measurements they provide the percentiles.

Comment: @Xi'an for (a) I was thinking that maybe as the CDF and PDF are related via de derivate ($F(x)=df(x)/dx$ the integral can be simplified. I have also realized that if I use $X_i$ as the lower limit of the integral I do note remove it as a variable...

Comment: @Xi'an the change of variable I used is $U = X_{i+1}$. And I want to marginalize the $U$, so I need to integrate over all the possible values of $U$ (am I right?). However as we are working with ordered values, by definition $U = X_{i+1} > X_{i}$. Why do you say the the constrain is $U \leq X_{i+1}$?

Comment: Right, $U_i>X_{i+\alpha}$ gives you a lower bound.

Comment: @Xi'an You are right! That indeed solves the problem, thank you very much!